# tkinter scrollbar alignment within LabelFrame

Tags: python, tkinter, alignment, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I want to display images on a Canvas within a Frame. For that I want the Canvas to have a Scrollbar. So I created a LabelFrame and assigned a Canvas for it:

```
    wrapper1 = LabelFrame(self.root)
    wrapper1.grid(row=1, columnspan=6, sticky="WE")

    image_canvas = Canvas(wrapper1)
    image_canvas.grid(sticky="NS")
```

Then I tried to add the Scrollbar:

```
    yscrollbar = Scrollbar(wrapper1, orient="vertical", command=image_canvas.yview)
    yscrollbar.grid(sticky="SNE", row=0, column=6)

    image_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
    image_canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: image_canvas.configure(scrollregion=image_canvas.bbox("all")))
```

All of it works apart from the fact that the Scrollbar doesn't properly stick to the right edge of the Frame:
[image: Scrollbar is in the middle of the frame]

As you can see it's rather in the middle. I also tried the same thing with buttons to no avail.  Prior to this I also set up some buttons on **self.root**. I don't know if they mess up the grid somehow, as they are not in the LabelFrame:

```
    BrowseButton = Button(self.root, text="Test1", command=self.browse)
    BrowseButton.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="WE")

    ConvertButton = Button(self.root, text="Test2", command=self.search)
    ConvertButton.grid(row=3, column=5, sticky="WE")

    SimilarImages = Button(self.root, text="Test3", command=self.compare)
    SimilarImages.grid(row=2, column=5, sticky="WE")
```

How do you make the Scrollbar stick correctly to the right side, while also filling out the whole Frame vertically?

Comment: I recommend doing a bit of research on the `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` methods. You're not using either, and a good rule of thumb is you should always use them in any widget that uses grid to arrange its children.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have no idea how changing the weight of the columns could've changed my problem but it did. I just thought that the scrollbar was assigned to the wrong column or I misaligned the grid in some way...Anyways, thanks for your answer!